# How to do a proper LEFT OUTER JOIN in N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have created an index in order to perform the following left outer join in N1ql:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON bucket("User::" || userId) WHERE docType="Order";

SELECT u.*, ARRAY_AGG(o) as orders
FROM bucket AS u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bucket AS o ON KEY "User::" || o.userId FOR u
WHERE u.docType="User"
AND o.docType="Order"
GROUP BY u;
```

This works fine when I have orders for that particular user. The problem is when I don't have any orders, then I get no results at all.

I have noticed that if I remove the `AND o.docType="Order"` statement from the query I get some results, but what happens if there are documents that also have a `userId` property? How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: In standard SQL you would need to move the condition `AND o.docType="Order"` to the join condition (out of the where). I don't know n1ql so I don't know how you specify more then one condition in the join clause there.

Comment: I don't think that N1QL allows for multiple conditions on the JOIN statement (http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html#story-h2-3), but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Then you need something like `AND (o.docType="Order" or o.docType IS NULL)`

Comment: I had tried this as well to no avail, I am guessing that since the `docType` is missing, then the key used in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will be null, yielding an empty result set.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I must have been doing something wrong, because it is working now... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

@a_horse_with_no_name is essentially correct. Use IS MISSING instead of IS NULL:

```
AND (o.docType="Order" OR o.docType IS MISSING)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @geraldss. Just to make sure, this approach obligates all documents to have a `docType` and not have a reference to the `userId`, correct?

Comment: No, this approach has no obligation. Always schemaless.

Comment: Hello @geraldss. For some reason, this is not working in a particular case. Right now I only have documents with the `docType="User"` in my bucket, meaning that I don't have any `Orders`. Making the query presented in the question with your suggestion returns an empty result set. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: EDIT: By creating a new index that has both conditions (docType=Order OR missing) I was able to obtain the expected results.